# Convert Pandas data frame to a list of tuples containing IDs and a weight

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, tuples, networkx

I have a data frame (called df) which is currently formatted like so:

```
    1      2     3
1   1      0.26  0.02
2   0.26   1     0.61
3   0.02   0.61  1
```

The IDs are connected by a value and I would like to somehow extract all unique ID values in order to have a more efficient way to add them to my graph on networkx.

The output should look like something like this:

```
ed_list = [(1,2,{'weight': 0.26}),(1,3,{'weight': 0.02}),(2,3,{'weight':0.61})]
```

At the moment I use the following method:

```
# Create matrix 
new_ = df.values
A_d = np.matrix(new_)
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(A_d)
```

I'm wondering if it would be easier/more efficient to create a List of tuples from my df that I could use to connect my nodes, where I could then add edges like so:

```
G.add_edges_from(ed_list)
```

EDIT: I have made a mistake in the previous version of my question -  the column and row names are just integers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try:

```
# this s is what you are looking for
s = df.where(df.index.values > df.columns.values[:,None]).stack().reset_index(name='weight')

# we can use dataframe directly
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(s,source='level_0',target='level_1', edge_attr='weight')
```

Or even simpler:

```
G = nx.from_pandas_adjacency(df)
```

Comment: both options works - thank you so much! However the second option returns all values in the df, whilst the first one returns only the unique combinations. Not sure if one will be more efficient than the other but I will update on this :-)