# convert pandas dataframe to list of tuple with unique pairs of integers as the first entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I have the following dataframe:

```
    ID weight  
 0  2    1
 1  3    1 
 2  4    1
 3  5    1
 4  6    1
 5  7    1
```

My goals is to generate a list of tuples that looks like this:

```
[(2,3,{'weight':1}),(2,4,{'weight':1}),(2,5,{'weight':1}),(2,6,{'weight':1}),(2,7,{'weight':1}),(3,4,{'weight':1}),(3,5,{'weight':1}),(3,6,{'weight':1}),(3,7,{'weight':1}),(4,5,{'weight':1})....]
```

Each entry should be a unique combination of integers from the `'ID'column` and the second entry should just be a weight set to 1.

Comment: Didn't you ask a similar question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64065398/convert-pandas-data-frame-to-a-list-of-tuples-containing-ids-and-a-weight/64065443#64065443)

Comment: @QuangHoang yes I did but I could not get it done myself - relatively new to all of this, it is all a bit overwhelming...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `combinations` from `itertools`, then form the desired tuple by unpacking the combination and adding your `{'weight' : 1}`.

```
from itertools import combinations
[(*x, {'weight': 1}) for x in combinations(df['ID'], 2)]
```

---

```
[(2, 3, {'weight': 1}),
 (2, 4, {'weight': 1}),
 (2, 5, {'weight': 1}),
 (2, 6, {'weight': 1}),
 (2, 7, {'weight': 1}),
 (3, 4, {'weight': 1}),
 (3, 5, {'weight': 1}),
 (3, 6, {'weight': 1}),
 (3, 7, {'weight': 1}),
 (4, 5, {'weight': 1}),
 (4, 6, {'weight': 1}),
 (4, 7, {'weight': 1}),
 (5, 6, {'weight': 1}),
 (5, 7, {'weight': 1}),
 (6, 7, {'weight': 1})]
```